# Numbers for $k^{th}$ power of sum of digits equal the sum of digits of $k^{th}$ power

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let us denote $D_*(n)$ to be the sum of digits of $n$. Then we can find numbers satisfying the formula $$D_*(n^2)=D^2_*(n)$$ 
Like : $11^2 =121 ,\; \;(1+1)^2= 1+2+1$ , other like $12^2=144, \; \; (1+2)^2=1+4+4$ and so on . Other such numbers being $13 ,22,111,212$. There are infinitely many such numbers follows from the fact that $10^k+1$ and $2(10^k+1)$ satisfy the condition for all values of $k$.

For $$D_*(n^3)=D_*^3(n)$$ 
We can have $101 , 1001 ,10001 \cdots$ and the non trivial ones $11 ,111,1011,10011,100011 \cdots$ .

I have observed while experimenting with this that 
$D_*[(1010010001)^3]= 64 = 4^3$ and one other $D_*[(11010010001)^3]=125 =5^3$
.Which motivates me to ask the following questions first related to the observation and second a general  one

> 1) For which $m$ does there exist a number $n$ such that $m^3=D_*(n^3)=D_*^3(n)$?
>
> 2)Are there numbers $n$ such that $D_*(n^k)=D_*^k(n)$ ?

Comment: $D_*(n)$ appears to be the **sum** of the digits of the number there, not just the count.  Is this what you wanted instead?

Comment: @ex0du5 yes the sum of the digits.... I made the changes

Comment: I think the numbers for the square case are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A061909 and perhaps there are some links there that would be of use for the other questions.